# 45 Degree Coupler on Fibre Optic cables

Tags: optics

I was reading through a research paper and they showed the following schematic:

[image]

I am not exactly sure what is meant by a 45 degree coupler so I looked online but there is no such thing as a 45 degree coupler. So I was wondering if a 45 degree coupler in this context is just a fibre optic cable that has been cut at a 45 degree angle?

Comment: See [How to reference material written by others](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) regarding your illustration. It would also provide some context to your question. Hit the [edit] link ...

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. A 45° cut on the fibre end will result in total internal reflection and a view at 90° to the axis of the fibre. (Image original.)*

Total internal reflection occurs if the angle of incidence is greater than a certain limiting angle, called the critical angle. For this application the critical angle would have to be < 45°.

Link: [Fibre optic surface plasmon resonance sensor system designed for smartphones by
Kort Bremer and Bernhard Roth](https://www.osapublishing.org/oe/fulltext.cfm?uri=oe-23-13-17179&id=321178).

Comment: Alternatively, one could metallize the 45-degree surface to guarantee reflection.